# Remove alias no longer functioning

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Every thing else appears to be running ok, creating a user, renaming a user, etc..  I have a series of unit tests to test each function out.

However, when I run the following code in C#:

```
                try
                {
                    var update = service.Users.Aliases.Delete(UserEmail, Alias);
                    update.Execute();

                    return true;

                }
```

Where UserEmail is the user's current email address/user account in google and alias is the alias from when the account was renamed.
I get an exception:

```
 Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nInvalid Input: resource_id [400]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Invalid Input: resource_id] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]\r\n]\r\n

 -2146233088
```

The user and alias do exist.

I also tried it in the "try it now" here:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/aliases/delete#auth

with the same effect.

I'm on 1.35.1.1281 for the directory API (most current)

Comment: Do you mean that when you do it in "try it now" it also returns the same error? So it doesn't work with both "try it now" and with the C# code?

Comment: Doesn't work with either on the google web doc "try it now" and it doesn't work in C# code.  I tried it both places.

Comment: Anyone??  This seems to be broken functionality...

Comment: I found the problem but this was working previously and should be working in your API.  The issue was the alias is case sensitive.  The alias (email address) should never be case sensitive... I'll adjust my code but you may want to take a look at your API.